# Why is google map api for route not displaying custom image?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I am working on an app, where I want to display the route between two points, and the route is working fine, but the custom image is not displaying correctly.
I am working with angular 8, I have tried everything and searched online but nothing seems to work

Please find below my code snippet:

```
map: google.maps.Map;
pos:any
deyMode="DRIVING"
origin:any={lat: 51.7519, lng: -1.2578}//{lat: 0, lng: 0}
destination:any={lat: 50.8429, lng: -0.1313}//{lat: 0, lng: 0}
directionsRenderer:any = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsService:any  = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
icons = {
    start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
        new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
        new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
        new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
    ), end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
        new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
        new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
        new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
    )
};
ngOnInit() {
    this.initMap()
}

initMap(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {            
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((pos:any) => {
            this.origin={'lat':pos.coords.latitude, 'lng':pos.coords.longitude}
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: this.origin, 
                disableDefaultUI: true,                 
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: true,
                overviewMapControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                    position:google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM 
                },
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                panControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            this.directionsRenderer.setOptions({
                polylineOptions: {
                  strokeColor: 'blue'
                }
            });
            this.directionsRenderer.setOptions({ suppressMarkers: true });
            this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
            this.calculateAndDisplayRoute();

        }), () => {
            console.log('Position is not available');
        }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        };
    } else console.log('No permission')
}
changeAm(val){
    this.deyMode=val
    this.calculateAndDisplayRoute()
}
calculateAndDisplayRoute() {
    this.directionsService.route({
        origin: this.origin,  
        destination: this.destination,  
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[this.deyMode]
    }, (response, status)=> {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            var leg = response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ];
            this.makeMarker( leg.start_location, this.icons.start, "title" );
            this.makeMarker( leg.end_location, this.icons.end, 'title' );
        }else window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    });
}     
makeMarker( position, icon, title ) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
     position: position,
     map: map,
     icon: icon,
     title: title
    });
}
```

How can I make the custom image to display on the map?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Your code for the icons is working without problem for me, it displays the blue / green markers as expected. Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce your issue from our side?